# Does SharePoint Groups title be unique in same site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, microsoft

Does SharePoint Groups title be unique in same site collection?
Having the same name for the group but be different.

We are creating subsites with the same name but unique URL, but then if a project is created with the same name the groups will have an appending number after its name.

Our project leader and possible our customers want the same title without the number because the groups are shown in a web part on the subsite.

Is it possible to fix without any dirty hack such as using javascript and trying the remove the appending number?

Can anyone from Microsoft confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint groups live on a site collection level, not on sub site level.
It is unable to create 2 SharePoint groups with the same name in one site collection.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.